# Updating a windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have an .exe written in .net (VB.net) 2.0.  I install it as a service using instalutil.exe.

My question is, do I need to fully uninstall the service and re-install it everytime I make an update to the exe?

I tried stopping the service and replacing the exe, but it does not seem to reflect the changes made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stop the service, replace the executable, and restart the service, it will use the new executable.

However, you need to make sure that the executable you're replacing is the one that's actually registered with the system.

Comment: It seems the key is to restart the service.  If we stop, replace the executable and just start it does not pick up the updated executable.  We have to specifically restart it.

Comment: @dtc Worked fine for me just stopping and starting, didn't need to specifically _re_start. Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the configuration programmatically, via the ChangeServiceConfig API.  I've done it, it works.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me before, I uninstall the previous one to make the new one work, so i think you really should.