# Swapping out the EXE referenced by a Windows Service

Tags: security, windows-services

Up front note:  this question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333667/updating-a-windows-service).  However that previous question was asked and answered a dozen years ago, and OS security measures have come a long way since.  (At least I hope they have!)  So I'd like a current answer based on more current versions of Windows.

The question is this:

When you create a Windows Service, as part of the definition there is a "Path to executable" -- the folder & EXE file that the service runs.  What all needs to be done to replace that EXE with a new/updated version?  I mean, is there anything beyond the obvious steps of:

1. Stop the service
2. Copy new EXE over old EXE
3. Start the service

I've tried these steps on a test VM running Windows Server 2016 and it seems to work.  But I'm just having trouble believing it could be that easy since it seems like a massive security gap... since the new EXE could be a legitimate bug fix, or straight-up malware, or anything else.